# Xcode Storyboard - How to change font size and position of elements between different iPhone screen sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

So I have the following layout in storyboards, everything works fine on the 3x screen sizes but I would like to try and tidy up the font sizes and the position of the button icon relative to the button text.

See below what I mean, basically what I want is for each screen size to look very similar to the 4.7 screen layout e.g. the spacing between the text and the icons (also how can I get the font to scale down slightly on the 4 inch screen as it looks too big but ok on the rest of the screens.

Any idea what constraints I need to put on the icons and text to get it to look the same on each screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In auto layout use multiplayer to increase and shrink the element. Please see the example below:

[image: Set the constraints as shown]
[image: Set the constraints with multiplier][image: Set height multiplier][image: Add constraints for label][image: Add centre contain for label to fix in centre][image: set minimum font size]

Now run your app and check in all device type. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, will give that ago, can you explain the multiplier values you have used? E.g. 1:1.5 what does that mean exactly? Also for the label the font size won't resize as the label can still display the text without reducing the font but it looks too big on the smaller screen

Comment: A multiplier is a value with respect to the view. You can set the multiplier to a constant to that its value increases or decreases with respect a particular view.

And for label, you can increase the leading and trailing constant of the label. but make sure you select "Minimum font size".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `autolayout`, you can set `aspect ratio` constraints for `width` and `height` of the `imageView` to the cell content view, that way, if the cell grows image will grow too.

The following link might be useful http://candycode.io/how-to-set-up-different-auto-layout-constraints-for-different-screen-sizes/